# Cloud service for storing audio and generating waveform data

Tags: javascript, audio, media-player, soundcloud, waveform

I'm currently updating a web page that provides some podcasts. The current site uses the official Soundcloud widget to display the podcasts while the new one is supposed to have a custom player.

As the soundcloud API is pretty lacking and they have closed registration of new apps I am unsure how to retrieve the waveform data and audio without using the widget.

I was wondering if there are other cloud services that provides this service or if there is a potential workaround for the soundcloud issue?

I tried implementing the official widget and simply hiding it with CSS and adding custom controls, but this does not give you access to the waveform data. Other than that I am unsure how to progress with this.

Comment: Take a look at [wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/)